# Swift | Parse nested JSON Data

Tags: json, swift, model, alamofire

Пытаюсь разобраться, как распарсить вложенный JSON. Всё время получаю либо nil, либо какую-то другую ошибку.

**Использую Alamofire. У меня есть JSON с вложенными данными:**

```
{
    "success": true,
    "result": {
        "previous": [
            {
                "id": 607,
                "doctor_id": 37,
                "filial_id": 10,
                "user_id": 36,
                "date": "2020-08-31",
                "time_start": "09:00",
                "time_end": "21:00",
                "datetime_ts_start": "1598508000",
                "datetime_ts_end": "1598551200",
                "free": 0,
                "created_at": "2020-02-13 16:41:17",
                "updated_at": "2020-09-01 12:46:58",
                "comment": null,
                "feedback": false,
                "filial": {
                    "id": 10,
                    "ones_id": "bab31a28-2375-11e4-bd23-00224d9f6e55",
                    "name": "Преображенская",
                    "address": "asfcsafsdfgsdfgsdfgdsfdsdfsdfssddgh",
                    "type": "asfcsafsdfgsdfgsdfgdsfdsdfsdfssddgh",
                    "metro": "asfcsafsdfgsdfgsdfgdsfdsdfsdfssddgh",
                    "created_at": "2020-02-13 16:41:15",
                    "updated_at": "2020-09-07 18:37:32",
                    "image": "1599493052.jpeg"
                },
                "doctor": {
                    "id": 37,
                    "ones_id": "4a1db7a5-0b8d-4fcd-86d8-dd98a6e1475b",
                    "name": "Иван Иванов Иванович",
                    "specialty": "врач-терапевт",
                    "cost": null,
                    "photo": "1596539470.jpeg",
                    "created_at": "2020-02-13 16:41:17",
                    "updated_at": "2020-02-13 16:41:17"
                }
            }
    "error": null
}
```

**Пример моих структур:**

```
struct Welcome: Codable {
    let success: Bool?
    let result: Result?
}

struct Result: Codable {
    let previous: [Previous]?
}

struct Previous: Codable {
    let id, doctorID, filialID, userID: Int?
    let date, timeStart, timeEnd, datetimeTsStart: String?
    let datetimeTsEnd: String?
    let free: Int?
    let createdAt, updatedAt: String?
    let comment: String?
    let feedback: Bool?
    let filial: Filial?
    let doctor: Doctor?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id
        case doctorID = "doctor_id"
        case filialID = "filial_id"
        case userID = "user_id"
        case date
        case timeStart = "time_start"
        case timeEnd = "time_end"
        case datetimeTsStart = "datetime_ts_start"
        case datetimeTsEnd = "datetime_ts_end"
        case free
        case createdAt = "created_at"
        case updatedAt = "updated_at"
        case comment, feedback, filial, doctor
    }
}
```

**Из всего этого ответа на экран мне нужно присвоить разным лейблам следующие поля:**
result - previous - date
result - previous - time_start
result - previous - filial - address
result - previous - filial - name
result - previous - filial - image
result - previous - doctor - name
result - previous - doctor - specialty
result - previous - doctor - photo

Каждая сущность (appointmetns + filial + doctor) должна располагаться в своей ячейке на tableview.

**Подскажите, пожалуйста:**

1. Как правильно декодировать весь JSON и поместить его в массив? Или возможно в разные массивы: appointmetns, doctors, filials. Я планировал этот массив/ массивы передать через completion из сетевого запроса во view controller, чтобы разместить инфу в labels.
2. Как работать с картинкой в данном случае?
3. Ещё, когда добавляю "enum CodingKey: String, CodingKey" появляется следующая ошибка: Type 'Appointment' does not conform to protocol 'Decodable'. Как можно решить эту проблему?

Comment: Добавьте примеры своих Codable.

Comment: @VAndrJ , добавил